# How can I use the real-time kernel with ZFS functionality in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: kernel, 22.04, zfs

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and installed a real-time kernel. Whenever I reboot with the RT kernel, I end up in a busybox prompt saying 'ZFS module not loaded.' I tried running

```
/sbin/depmod zfs
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you on ARM (e.g. Raspberry Pi)? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2407436

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here, the Ubuntu realtime kernels do not include the ZFS modules by default.

[Generic kernel module list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/amd64/linux-image-5.15.0-102-generic/5.15.0-102.112) (5.15.0-102.112):

> ```
> fuse-module
> ivtv-modules
> kvm-api-4
> linux-image
> redhat-cluster-modules
> spl-dkms
> spl-modules
> v4l2loopback-dkms
> v4l2loopback-modules
> virtualbox-guest-modules
> zfs-dkms
> zfs-modules
> ```

[Realtime kernel module list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-1032-realtime/5.15.0-1032.35) (5.15.0-1032.35):

> ```
> fuse-module
> ivtv-modules
> kvm-api-4
> linux-image
> redhat-cluster-modules
> virtualbox-guest-modules
> ```

I think the reasoning here is that the realtime kernels are not normally used for applications that also involve fileservers and the ZFS filesystem.

So it seems the solution here is to compile your own version of the realtime kernel with the modules you want.